# HTML5 Table cell padding - different in browsers

Tags: css, html, html-table, cross-browser, padding

I've broken this down to a fairly simple example.

For me, it looks different in Chrome 7.0 than it does in Firefox 3.6.12.  IE 9 beta looks like Chrome.

I'd like to be able to set padding on the TD, and have it render with the same height in all browsers.  Currently, with the 10px top padding, the cells in Chrome look taller than in Firefox.

I've tried using Eric's reset css, it doesn't change the result
Any ideas why these are being rendered differently?

An example of how it looks is here - http:// yfrog. com/5zqa7p

And the Code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>padding test</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<style>
td { width: 100px; height:100px; background: green; padding: 10px 0 0 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>TEST</td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's apparently a bug in the way Firefox and Chrome handle padding in table cells in HTML5: 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50633

When you try your markup and CSS with 0 padding, they're the same. When you switch the DOCTYPE to be not HTML5 they are the same as well.

Comment: Yup - removing the doctype makes both browsers render it the same (IE too)

Answer (score 9):

For HTML5 some browsers add 2px to table cells with images if line-height is default. It's flagged as a bug, don't expect it to always be like this.

```
table { line-height: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this behavior is caused by different defaults of `box-sizing` values on TD elements. Take a look at the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

Box-sizing is luckily supported on all major browsers, see http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

But there are issues in browsers preventing you from overriding default `box-sizing` value, especially when you are working with TD, the behavior is almost unpredictable across browsers.

In [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/22s9G/7/) the most stable behavior across browsers is shown by `border-box` and `content-box` on a DIV element.

So just avoid using padding when height is fixed, and instead just wrap TD contents with additional padding container as a simple and bulletproof workaround.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
td { padding: 10px 0 0 0; }
```

This says: `padding-top: 10px;`, replace the 10px with 0 and *hopefully* it'll be the same. This means that Firefox and IE9 are not accounting for padding. (I think)

Answer (score 1):

It should be written like this `padding: 0 10px 0 10px;` otherwise browsers wont fully support the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I found browser-specific CSS ([from here](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/get-grips-css3-multiple-background-images)) for Firefox is a bit descriptive like:

```
background-color:#447d9a;
background-image:url('img/bg.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

So, I think, for firefox, padding can be descriptive rather brief (`padding:10px 0 0 0;`):

```
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
```

It's a solution (or can be a solution) only for Firefox; and can work for the other browsers to debug specifically.

Comment: That's actually not specific to Firefox. Both the shorthand and longform versions of the padding properties are part of the CSS 2.1 spec and supported in all browsers. (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties)