# CSS Hover Not Working in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a table with a hover affect on the rows. It works fine in Internet Explorer, but when testing in Chrome, the right hand corner of the row color gets messed up. It isn't fully hovering. Any suggestions? Here is a link to the code: http://codepen.io/ChaseHardin/pen/DyuEf    or code below.

HTML:

```
 <table class="tableStyle hoverTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="theadCustom"></th>
                        <th class="theadCustom"></th>
                        <th class="theadCustom"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr class="even myHover">
                        <td class="tdCustom">85% $CEZ</td>
                        <td class="tdCustom">Top 1% $F</td>
                        <td class="tdCustom">10% $BMI</td>
                    </tr><!-- Table Row -->

                    <tr class="odd myHover">
                        <td class="tdCustom">BW: 91 lbs</td>
                        <td class="tdCustom">WW: 781 lbs</td>
                        <td class="tdCustom">YW: 1,420 lbs</td>
                    </tr><!-- Darker Table Row -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

CSS:

```
.tableStyle {
    border: #ccc 2px solid;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gabriola";
    font-size: 25px;

    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.even {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#f6f6f6));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f8f8f8,  #f6f6f6);
}

.odd {
    background: #fafafa;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa);
}

.tdCustom {
    border: #ccc 2px solid;
    padding: 15px;
}

.theadCustom {
    padding:21px 25px 22px 25px;

    background: #ededed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed,  #ebebeb);
}

.myHover:hover {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#f0f0f0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f2f2,  #f0f0f0);  
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

.hoverTable {
    width: 80%;
    border-collapse:collapse;

    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's something you don't hear often.. *"It works fine in Internet Explorer"* .. but not in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome, padding, tables, and box-sizing seems to cause funkiness. Is the 15px padding required? (Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134107/html5-table-cell-padding-different-in-browsers)

Comment: Thanks @JackPattishallJr. that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a result of the `paddining: 15px` on the `.tableStyle` element. Removing that resolves the issue without affecting the display.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/voxin)

```
.tableStyle {
    border: #ccc 2px solid;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gabriola";
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want to add padding to the `table` element, you should use `border-spacing: 15px` instead. It's worth noting that the `border-collapse` property value needs to be `separate` rather than `collapse` in order for `border-spacing` to have an effect.